# Enumerable extension methods inaccessible on GroupCollection

Tags: c#, regex, linq, interface

According to [the documentation](//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.groupcollection), the `GroupCollection` Class implements the generic `IEnumerable` interface. Its extension methods are even listed below on that page. Yet, I'm getting

> Compilation error (line 16, col 4): 'GroupCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Skip' and no accessible extension method 'Skip' accepting a first argument of type 'GroupCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

for the following code:

```
using System.Linq;
var currency = "HUF";
var origin = "Modlin";
var changes = 3;
System.Console.WriteLine(
    new[] {
        $"Cost: 50 {currency}",
        $"Departure airport: {origin}",
        $"Number of changes: {changes}"
    }[
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(
            "variable elem: blablaoriginbleble",
            "(currency)|(origin)|(changes)"
        )[0]
        .Groups
        .Skip(1)
        .Select((m, i) => (m, i))
        .First(p => p.Item1.Success)
        .Item2
    ]);
```

The error goes away if I surround L11-15 with `((System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group>)` and `)`. Why is it necessary?

What's even stranger is that omitting `[0]` and `.Groups` (not semantically equivalent, just for the sake of experiment) leads to no error as well. In that case the extension methods `Skip`, `Select` and `First` are called on an instance of `MatchCollection`. Which also implements `IEnumerable` and it seems behaviour should be analogous.

Comment: Could the reason be that `GroupCollection` (unlike `MatchCollection`) implements `IEnumerable` twice (with different generic parameters) and the compiler doesn't know which one to use? And just gives a confusing error message which doesn't explain it? If so, does the solution become easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT 2:

I just tested your code in .NET 6 and got the same error message. I changed:

```cs
.Skip(1)
```

to:

```cs
.Skip<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group>(1)
```

and it worked. I believe the issue is that, because `GroupCollection` implements `IEnumerable<T>` twice for two specific types `T` (`Group` and `KeyValuePair<string,Group>>`), the type cannot be inferred from usage. This means that you need to specify the generic type parameter when calling `Skip` so it knows which implementation to use. It's pretty much as you surmised in your comment on the question.

EDIT:

I'll leave my original answer below but, thinking about your code, it appears that you may be using top-level statements, so that would imply that you are using .NET 6. I guess we'll see when you respond. If you are then I'm not sure what the reason would be.

ORIGINAL:

That documentation is for .NET 6. I'm guessing that you're using an earlier version. You should select your .NET version in the upper-left of that page and I expect you'll find that, in that version, `GroupCollection` implements far fewer interfaces. For instance, it only implements `ICollection` in .NET Framework 4.8. What you can do is call `Cast<T>` to get an `IEnumerable<T>` and then access all the extensions methods for that interface:

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var currency = "HUF";
var origin = "Modlin";
var changes = 3;

System.Console.WriteLine(
    new[] {
        $"Cost: 50 {currency}",
        $"Departure airport: {origin}",
        $"Number of changes: {changes}"
    }[
        Regex.Matches(
            "variable elem: blablaoriginbleble",
            "(currency)|(origin)|(changes)"
        )[0]
        .Groups
        .Cast<Group>()
        .Skip(1)
        .Select((m, i) => (m, i))
        .First(p => p.Item1.Success)
        .Item2
    ]);
```

Comment: Yea, .NET 6. But it's already in .NET 5 and .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: @ByteEater, see my new edit.